# Module Not Found Error after library installation

Tags: python

I am trying to use the Scratch library.

For example:

```py
from scratch.probability import normal_cdf
from scratch.linear_algebra import Vector, dot
#...
```

I installed Scratch using `pip install scratch` but I receive this error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scratch'`.

Can you help me?

Comment: `pip install scratch-probability` ??

Comment: try `pip install scratch` and see the [two notes](https://github.com/joelgrus/data-science-from-scratch#data-science-from-scratch) in the readme.

Comment: which OS are you using? Which python version? try `pip list` and see if `scratch` is somewhere in the result.

Comment: Yes in pip list I find scratch-probability but when I import it: from scratch-probability import normal_cdf
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: It might help to format your code as code, and to include other things you've tried an edited version of the question, rather than in comments.

Answer (score 2):

`pip install scratch` will install this: https://pypi.org/project/scratch/

But I guess that what you want to use is that: https://github.com/joelgrus/data-science-from-scratch

The second one is not meant to be installed through `pip` but used directly in a clone of the project as documented in its README.

About `pip install scratch-probability` (https://pypi.org/project/scratch-probability/#description), as it's not documented, you need to go check the content of the tarball to know how the package inside are named (if they are what's expected).